# detached entity passed to persist in OneToMany relationship JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

So I have this 2 JPA entities : Task and Imputation

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String description;

}


@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Imputation {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private Task task;

    private LocalDate day;
    private Double workload;
}
```

I want the Id column in my Imputation table to be the primary key of the task table .

For example : if my task table looks like this :

```
id | name | description 
5    task5   desc5
6    task6   desc 6
```

then i would like my imputation table to look like this:

```
 task_id | day  | workload 
  5        date1  0.5
  6        date2  1.2
```

here is the code that's causing the error  :

```
Task task1 = taskService.getTask(1);
            Task task2 = taskService.getTask(2);
            Imputation imputation1 = new Imputation(task1,LocalDate.of(2022,10,22),0.5,userService.getUser("consultant4"));
            Imputation imputation2 = new Imputation(task2,LocalDate.of(2022,10,23),1.2,userService.getUser("consultant5"));

            imputationService.saveImputation(imputation1);
            imputationService.saveImputation(imputation2);
```

Comment: what odes your service do?

Comment: @juwil

public Imputation saveImputation(Imputation imputation) {
        log.info("saving imputation for task {} and user {}",imputation.getTask().getName(), imputation.getEmployee().getUsername());

        return imputationRepository.save(imputation);
    }

Comment: so I reckon, the detached eintity is the task (task1 as well as task2). I don't know whether your service method getTask(..) and your calling method are marked transactional in any way. Your code must be executed inside ONE transaction. so best way would be to mark the calling method transactional and mark getTask transactional as well. That way the getTask joins the outer transaction and the task will not be detached inside the caling mehtod.